# MessageBodyWriter not found vogella tutorial

Tags: java, json, tomcat, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am attempting to recreate the most excellent vogella tutorial for create REST with java, JAX-RS and Jersey.

I'm using eclipse Kepler with Java-EE perspective, tomcat 7.0.

I have create the Todo class, the TodoResource class with the appropriate annotations and deployed on tomcat 7. I have imported the jaxrs-ri libs into the WEB-INF/lib folder as instructed.

Todo class:

```
package com.vogella.jersey.jaxb.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Todo {
  private String summary;
  private String description;
  public String getSummary() {
    return summary;
  }
  public void setSummary(String summary) {
    this.summary = summary;
  }
  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }
  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }


}
```

TodoResource with annotations:

```
package com.vogella.jersey.jaxb.model;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/todo")
public class TodoResource {
  // This method is called if XMLis request
  @GET
  @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
  public Todo getXML() {
    Todo todo = new Todo();
    todo.setSummary("This is my first todo");
    todo.setDescription("This is my first todo");
    return todo;
  }

  // This can be used to test the integration with the browser
  @GET
  @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_XML })
  public Todo getHTML() {
    Todo todo = new Todo();
    todo.setSummary("This is my first Todo");
    todo.setDescription("This is my first Todo");
    return todo;
  }

}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>com.vogella.jersey.first</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.vogella.jersey.jaxb</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have also created the client as instructed.

Test.java:

```
package com.vogella.jersey.first.client;

import java.net.URI;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse;
import org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MediaTypes;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {



    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);

    WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI());


    System.out.println(target.path("rest").path("todo").request()

            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML ).get(Response.class)

            .toString());

    System.out.println(target.path("rest").path("todo").request()

            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ).get(Response.class)

            .toString());


  }

  private static URI getBaseURI() {

      return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.jaxb").build();

  }
}
```

Everything works perfectly for the MediaType.APPLICATION_XML - the server returns:

```
InboundJaxrsResponse{ClientResponse{method=GET, uri=http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.jaxb/rest/todo, status=200, reason=OK}}
```

However, for the MediaType APPLICATION_JSON - which is what I actually need, I get an error:

```
InboundJaxrsResponse{ClientResponse{method=GET, uri=http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.jaxb/rest/todo, status=500, reason=Internal Server Error}}
```

Tomcat clearly shows me the problem - it seems to me it doesn't know how to return a JSON response -

```
Nov 02, 2014 11:59:19 AM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.vogella.jersey.jaxb.model.Todo, genericType=class com.vogella.jersey.jaxb.model.Todo.
```

My understanding is that the jaxrs-ri 2.13 bundle includes everything required including dependencies to let me do this - and that I don't need to add any kind of JSON provider. I have done so anyway, I have tried adding gson for example,  I have downloaded the moxy jars and attempting to add them to my WEB-INF/lib folder and deploy - all to no avail. I don't know if I'm completely out in the weeds, or if I'm missing something simple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding is that the jaxrs-ri 2.13 bundle includes everything required including dependencies to let me do this - and that I don't need to add any kind of JSON provider.

That's actually incorrect. As stated at the [Jersey User Guide 8.1. JSON](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json)

> Jersey JSON support comes as a set of extension modules where each of these modules contains an implementation of a Feature that needs to be registered into your Configurable instance (client/server). There are multiple frameworks that provide support for JSON processing and/or JSON-to-Java binding. The modules listed below provide support for JSON representations by integrating the individual JSON frameworks into Jersey. At present, Jersey integrates with the following modules to provide JSON support:
>
> - **MOXy** - JSON binding support via MOXy is a default and preferred way of supporting JSON binding in your Jersey applications since Jersey 2.0. When JSON MOXy module is on the class-path, Jersey will automatically discover the module and seamlessly enable JSON binding support via MOXy in your applications. (See Section 4.3, “Auto-Discoverable Features”.)
> - Among a few others

So the main Jersey download doesn't come with these extra modules. We need to obtain them separately. That being said, the easiest way to get the required [`jersey-media-moxy`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-moxy/2.13) is through Maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using Maven (which looking through [the tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html), it doesn't), you're going to have to do some searching for the dependencies. The `jersey-media-moxy` artifact has 16 dependencies, but Fortunately, most are contained within the Jersey distribution. So after filtering out what was already included in the Jersey distro, these are the remaining jars you will have to find on your own (I just created a User Library to test out)

[image]

Adding these dependencies will get [the example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html) up and running. Tested and works as expected after adding these.

Now you have Eclipse, which I assume came with the Maven (m2e) plugin. So maybe the easiest way to get these dependencies is to create a new Maven project, and add the dependency shown above. After you build the project, maven should download all the extra dependencies into your local Maven Repo. Just grab them from there for your main project.

---

**Other Resources/Notes**

- [Jersey User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html)
- I would download the [Jersey Example package](https://jersey.java.net/download.html), which is more up to date then the tutorial you are using.
- If you don't know Maven, I would strongly suggest learning at least the basic of dependency management, and let the build framework grab all the dependencies for you. Also all the examples in the examples package uses Maven, so it would help to know the basics.

Comment: thanks very much - your answer was bang on the money. I'm going to spend some time learning Maven as you suggest -it's pretty easy since I'm using eclipse anyway and it sure seems slick. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using **Jersey-2**

Web.xml Configuration

```
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servletclass>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.oracle.restful</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

**List of Libraries required**

1. org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.6.3.jar
2. org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.6.3.jar
3. org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.6.3.jar
4. org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.6.3.jar
5. jersey-media-moxy-2.23.1.jar
6. jersey-entity-filtering-2.23.1.jar

Run project it will work. Also check your JAXB classed because it will internally use xml annotation to convert pojo object to JAXB

Answer (score -1):

Have you written any custom MessageBodyWriter for your marshalling from Java to JSON. If yes then you need to have the @Produces annotation with 'application/json' in the provider implementation. For more details refer http://h2labz.blogspot.in/2014/12/marshalling-java-to-json-in-jax-rs.html