# Glassfish :MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException in Jersy Client

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jax-rs, jersey-client

Hi All I was trying to create a rest web-service from scratch. Here is my Service part

```
@Path("/Phones")
public class PhonessResource {

 @GET
 @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  public Response getAllNumbers(){
      List<PhoneDetail> list = PhoneDirectoryDao.getInstance().getAllNumbers();
      GenericEntity<List<PhoneDetail>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<PhoneDetail>>(list) {};
      Response response =Response.ok(entity).status(200).build();
      return response;//PhoneDirectoryDao.getInstance().getAllNumbers();
    }
 }
```

My data Model : I a had my getters and setters along with another constructor that take all property ,I didn't paste it to less the question length ,I use the same data model in client and server

```
@XmlRootElement(name="PhoneDetail")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder={"id","firstName","lastName","address","phoneNo","timeStamp"})
public class PhoneDetail {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNo;
    private Timestamp timeStamp;

    public PhoneDetail() {}
}
```

Then I create a java client to test the service .I am using NETBEANS IDE ,so I choose default option in IDE to create it

[image]

Thus I create a Jersey Client

```
public class PhoneCLient {
    private WebTarget webTarget;
    private Client client;
    private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/Phones/webresources";

    public PhoneCLient() {
        client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
        webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("Items");
    }


    public <T> T getAllNumbers_XML(Class<T> responseType) throws ClientErrorException {
        WebTarget resource = webTarget;
        return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(responseType);
    }

    public <T> T getAllNumbers_JSON(Class<T> responseType) throws ClientErrorException {
        WebTarget resource = webTarget;
        return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(responseType);
    }
}
```

But It gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/xml, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:988)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:833)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:768)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:740)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:650)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:421)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:646)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:275)
    at PhoneDirectoryClient.rest.PhoneCLient.getAllNumbers_XML(PhoneCLient.java:45)
```

But when I test the service in Browser or RestClient Browser plugin it works fine .
 Can anybody tell me what went wrong ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Xml, if you have all the dependencies that come with Jersey, it should work out the box for the client API. You might not have added all of them. I see you aren't using Maven, which I would strongly advise doing. But I'll provide both way to handle this.

### XML

**Maven:**

Only dependencies you'll nee to get the client up and running (with JAXB xml support)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Doesn't get much simpler :-)

**Non-Maven:**

So using a Maven project, I added the above dependency, and these are all the transitive dependencies it pulled in. In your non Maven project, you will need to manually add all these jars.

[image]

If you go to the [Jersey Hompage](https://jersey.java.net/), go to Downloads, and download the "`Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 RI bundle`. You should find all these dependencies in there. You should add all the ones needed, into your project

**Note:** Netbeans already comes with the `Jersey 2.0 (JAX-RS RI)` library. You could instead simply add that library to your project. Just right click on the [Libraries] node in your project, and select [Add Library]. You should see the Jersey in the dialog. This solution is probably the easiest, but it will import all the Jersey dependencies, more than is required for the client API

### JSON

JSON requires another dependency:

**Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
```

**Non-Maven**

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26706617/2587435) for an image and further explanation.

---

Just having these dependencies on the classpath should work, without any special configuration.

#### UPDATE

In newer versions of the Jersey client, `jersey-media-jaxb` is not pulled in anymore and you will need to manually add it for XML/JAXB support.

Comment: Actually all this jars were present in my Java Client, Actually i Just write code manually for client with out using Netbeans built in functionality ,It  start working. Thanks for your Maven and json Tip

Comment: Update : `jersey-media-jackson` is no more available, it's `jersey-media-json-jackson` instead.

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID it never _was_ available. It was a typo. Thanks.