# How to post a json object to rest endpoint in Jersey client

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-client

I use Jersey filter to get the request information like sessionID, TimeStamp.....

Now I want to convert these values to a JSON object and post to another rest endpoint. I tried with the following code but it doesn't work.

```
private String SessionID;
private String TimeStamp;
private String Path;
private String UserName;

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, 
ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

   System.out.println("response:" + responseContext.getEntity());
  } 

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws 
IOException {

  Date requestDate = new Date();
  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
  TimeStamp = simpleDateFormat.format(requestDate);

  SessionID = requestInfo.getRequestedSessionId();
  UserName = requestInfo.getRemoteUser();
  Path = requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath();

  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("timestamp", TimeStamp);
  map.put("sessionId", SessionID);
  map.put("username", UserName);
  map.put("path", Path);

  JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
  json.putAll(map);
  sendRequest(json);

  System.out.println("========================================");
  System.out.println(json.toJSONString());
  }



private void sendRequest(JSONObject jsonObject) {

  Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
  WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/test");
  Response res = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(jsonObject));
  if (res.getStatus() == 200) {
     System.out.println("ok");
   }
}
```

I got the org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException

/test is just a simple test service which takes JSON and returns a string

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945281/glassfish-messagebodyprovidernotfoundexception-in-jersy-client

Comment: jsonObject.toString()