# Problem with CSV file upload with Swagger

Tags: java, file-upload, swagger, multipartform-data

I'm trying to implement a RESTful API with Swagger 2.0 tu upload a CSV file with Java backend; This is the swagger definition for the API:

```
/mobileCommunications/importCallDetails:
  post:
    operationId: importCallDetails
    summary: Uploads a file that contains the call details for a specific period.
    tags:
      - MobileCommunications
    consumes:
      - multipart/form-data
    parameters:
      - in: formData
        name: upfile
        type: file
    responses:
       '200':
          description: file uploaded successfully
```

And, that's the code generated by Swagger:

```
@POST
@Path("/importCallDetails")
@Consumes({ "multipart/form-data" })
@Produces({ "application/json; charset=utf-8" })
@io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation(value = "Uploads a file that contains the call details for a specific period.", notes = "", response = Void.class, tags={ "MobileCommunications", })
@io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses(value = { 
    @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "file uploaded successfully", response = Void.class) })
public Response importCallDetails(MultipartFormDataInput input,@Context SecurityContext securityContext,@Context Request request,@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws ApplicationException;
```

And this is my controller code (which is not executed at all anyway that's why it's empty):

```
@Override
public Response importCallDetails(MultipartFormDataInput input, SecurityContext securityContext, Request request,
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws ApplicationException {

    return null;
}
```

And this is the maven dependencies related to this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

But, i still get this error in the backend whenever i try to upload the file:

```
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryvmfNnOPmhX557ZUx, type=interface org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput, genericType=interface org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput.
```

I'm stuck with this problem for about a week now and i don't make any progress toward the solution, so any help will make a difference here :)

Thank you

Comment: If you're not using Maven, I would suggest you use maven to setup your dependencies. I think the answer to your question is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945281/glassfish-messagebodyprovidernotfoundexception-in-jersy-client

Answer (score 0):

With JavaSpring + Swagger:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/yourPathValue", consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) // MULTIPART_FORM_DATA = "multipart/form-data"
public void yourMethodName(@RequestParam("csv") final MultipartFile csv) {
   // TODO your awesome logic
}
```